# Form Submition Ajax call in jquery mobile

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I want to submit form throught ajax call in jquery mobile.

My script is that

```
<script>
function confirm(){

var user_name = $('#login_form').find('input[name="user_name"]').val();
    $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: $('#login_form').find('input[name="action"]').val(),
            data: "val=" + user_name, 
           success: function(data){

                alert(data); 
            }
        });

}
</script>
```

My Form is here....

Name

                    


Email
                    

Password

Please it is  urgent..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function confirm(){

var frm = $('#login_form');

frm.submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');
            }
            error: function(xhr,err){
                 alert(err);
            }

        });

        return false;
    });
}

You can use this function to post your data...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this function also...

$("#login_form").submit(function() {

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: $(this).attr('action'),
           data: $("#login_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
           error:function(xhr,err){
               alert(err);
            }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```